# Can power series method fails to solve differential equation at ordinary point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

Is there a sufficient condition if satisfied by a differential equation at an ordinary point ensures finding the solution using power series method?

In other words, can power series method fails to solve differential equation at ordinary point?

Comment: Obviously, the method can not be applied if the ODE in all its terms can not be expanded as convergent power series.

Comment: Though you do not say so, you seem to be talking about *linear* differential equations. "Differential equations" by itself can include highly non-linear equations, such as $\sin\frac 1{y''} = x\cos y$. Even for ordinary points of linear equations, it is quite possible for the power series solution found to have a radius of convergence of $0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair could you please give me a reference or some link to read about such cases or how to test if a certain differential equation could be solved using power series?